# How Can I Block Pop-Under Ads?

Tags: google-chrome, popups

Lots of pop-under ads get through Chrome's built-in popup blocker. How can I block such ads? Whenever I click on the links, pop-under ads will be activated. How can I block these ads? I have been looking for extensions but could not find anything that really works.
Thank you.

Comment: Do you have an example URL?

Comment: http://www.tripadvisor.com/

Comment: http://www.tv-links.eu/movies/

Answer (score 2):

In Firefox, Adblock Plus eliminates all ads from pages I visit including pop-unders. There is a version for Chrome which you can try.

Download the Chrome version of the extension from [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock-plus-beta/cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb).

There are a few ads that are allowed by the extension for certain reasons. They can, however, be easily added to the list of ads to be blocked.

Comment: Adblock Plus for Chrome blocks some popups, but not those from tripadvisor. Both from my experience and from what other people say. Very strange.

Answer (score 1):

[Popper Stopper Pro](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/popper-stopper-pro/jmjbmlfmmendpkpiggcfpjcpbbpedhha) for Chrome

As one of the reviews says: "it just works!!!"