# Block TripAdvisor pop-ups in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, popups

tripadvisor.com has very annoying pop-ups that appear after certain clicks. How can I block them? I use Chrome and already have the AdBlock Plus extension installed, subscribing to Fanboy's Adblock list - that doesn't block it. I've even added personal filters for the following URLs:

```
www.tripadvisor.*/CommercePopunderEnhanced*
www.tripadvisor.*/ExitWindowEnhanced*
```

but the pop-ups still come up. Surely there is some extension that will let me specify: never show any pop-up for this domain?

Comment: A similar question was asked here http://superuser.com/questions/485332/how-can-i-block-pop-under-ads and the asker seems satisfied with the answer. I hesitate to keep installing more addons, but TripAdvisor annoys me so much that I might eventually try this.